# Sympy Line3D intersection with cube

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, sympy, computational-geometry

I am developing a program where the user can create any line providing two points, and I need an algorithm for getting the intersection between the line created and a cube of 200x200 dimensions.

I was thinking in evaluating the line values at 100 units on each axis (positive and negative) and then comparing it. If the result is higher than 100 units, the line has already crossed a cube face. Then the lines may pass through the edge or the vertices of the cube, so there should be a greater or equal operator.

The problem I have is that I can not find how to create the line equation properly, the sympy library has limitations with 3D geometry. Code:

```py
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")
line = Line3D(Point3D(1, 1, 1), Point3D(3, 2, 2)).equation(x, y, z)
print(line)
print(simplify(line[0] - line[1]))
```

Output:

(-x + 2*y - 1, -x + 2*z - 1)

2*y - 2*z

Comment: Just what do you mean by "a cube of 200x200 dimensions"? Do you mean a 3-dimensional cube (as in your code example) where each side has length `200` (not as in your code example)? Where is the cube in your code? Why did you expect to get a single equation out of your code? (A line in 3D space is defined by two linear equations, not one). You write of "the intersection between the line created and a cube" but such an intersection generally involves infinitely many points in the cube's interior and two points on the boundary. Overall, your question is not clear--please clarify.

Comment: The cube does not exist in my code, it is a concept for rendering the end of the line. I thought there is one equation per line, like ax + by + cz = d. I only need the boundary points for rendering the line.

Comment: One equation like `ax + by + cz = d` defines a plane in 3D space, not a line. You need two such equations for a line, though there are other ways to define a line, such as two points on the line. So to clarify, do you want the two boundary points of the intersection of the line defined by two points and the cube of size `200` centered at the origin and aligned with the axes? What should be done if there is only one boundary point or no intersection at all? Finally, is sympy actually required?

Comment: That's it, the line is defined by two points inside the cube

Answer (score 1):

The line has the vector equation

```
P(t) = Q + t.QR
```

where `Q`, `R` are the two points that define it.

Presumably, your cube is axis aligned and defined as the range `[X0, X1] x [Y0, Y1] x [Z0, Z1]`.

The intersection with the plane `X = X0` is obtained by

```
X0 = Qx + t (Rx - Qx),
```

i.e.

```
tx0 = (X0 - Qx) / (Rx - Qx).
```

Repeating for the six planes, you will obtain three intervals of `t`*, and you have to take their intersection, given by

```
[max(tx0, ty0, tz0), min(tx1, ty1, tz1)].
```

(*If necessary, swap the values so that `t0 < t1`.)

If `tmax > tmin`, the range is empty and there is no intersection. Otherwise plug the values of t in the first equation to get the coordinates.

---

If your cube is not axis-aligned, rotate space to make it so, find the intersections, and counter-rotate.

If the line is limited to a line segment, also take the intersection of the `t` range with `[0, 1]`.

Comment: What does t. means?

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Do you know about vectors and parametric equations ?

Comment: Only the basis, I have only worked with 2D equations

Answer (score -2):

I have finally achieved a non-efficient but simple solution. I have created 8 planes, one per cube face and intersect the line with all of them. If the point's coordinates is in range, the line crosses that face so that point is one vertex.